# What is the correct way to do BigDecimal comparison

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, bigdecimal, android-lint

Since recently, (I think it's since I converted my code to kotlin but not sure), Android Studio show me a warning when I write

```
if (myValue.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0)
```

The message say "Call replaceable with binary operator" and replace my code with

```
if (myValue > BigDecimal.ZERO)
```

I noticed I also use

```
if (myValue.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0
```

But this time I got no warning and if I try to replace it, it doesn't work

```
if (myValue == BigDecimal.ZERO) // DOES NOT WORK
```

Why does `> ZERO` work but not `== ZERO`? Why every thread that I saw on stackoverflow (for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164521/compare-if-bigdecimal-is-greater-than-zero)) recommand using `compareTo` but `> ZERO` work and is recommended by Android Studio?

Comment: What happens if you do `myValue == 0` ?

Comment: `BigDecimal("0.00") == BigDecimal.ZERO` would return false

Comment: I have the same question, did you find a good answer?

Comment: @dicarlomagnus Since then I switched to kotlin and made kotlin extension functions for better readability and hide the mess

Answer (score 11):

tl;dr:

- `val1 > val2` -> `val1.compareTo(val2) > 0`
- `val1 == val2` -> `val1.equals(val2)`
- `BigDecimal.equals(...)` does not work the way you expect it to.

---

This happens because Kotlin replaces the binary operators `>`, `>=`, `<`, and `<=` with a call to `.compareTo`, so `val1 > val2` is exactly the same as `val1.compareTo(val2) > 0`.

However, the issue is that `val1 == val2` is replaced with a call to `.equals`, and `BigDecimal.equals` does not behave the way you think it should. The "correct" way to check for being equal is what you already had, which is `val1.compareTo(val2) == 0`

You can read a discussion that Kotlin contributors had on this issue starting in 2016 [over here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/bigdecimal-comparison/1828/5).

Comment: I would like to simplify it, although the code docs for BigDecimal.compareTo say this: "This method is provided in preference to individual methods for each of the six boolean comparison operators".